# How does work AS OF clause in system-versioned temporal tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

You need to query the customer table to return the state of the table before these changes were made - which query should you use?

Correct answer is: this query uses as of sub-clause to return the state of the customer table before changes were made.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.customer 
FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '2017-10-01 00:00:00' 
ORDER BY customerID;
```

Question: How does, in this case, `AS OF` clause work? How this can query history table for `'2017-10-01 00:00:00'`?

Comment: Hi. I'm afraid this question is a bit unclear, can you clarify exactly what it is you're asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working with **system-versioned temporal tables**. First introduced at `ANSI SQL 2011` and then at `SQL SERVER 2016`.

This tables have two control columns, `sysStartDate` and `sysEndDate`, which specifies the period for which a record is valid (when a record is still valid end-date is set to `9999-12-31`).

This clause, `FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF <date_time>` will query data that was valid for a specified date time. That means, it will filter out data with sysStartDate bigger than `<date_time>` and sysEndDate smaller than `<date_time>`, i.e., you are querying data that was valid at `<date_time>`.